# Finite Automata Definition of language

Tags: finite-automata

Hi I am trying to define a language accepted by an FA in simple terms the FA is:

> [image: s]

I think it is the language with strings

(not starting with ab and
not having substring bb and also ending with an a)
and also the NULL string

But I do not know if this is the shortest definition or correct at all?

Comment: Is x1 the start and x1 or x3 possible ends?

Comment: x1 is both the initial and final state. Only x1 is a possible end.

Comment: @deviantfan No x1 is both start and *accepting* state x3 is dead state

Comment: All the even length strings which do not have 'b' at any of the even positions ?

Comment: @user550 "Finite Automata Definition of language" ?? What you need English description or RE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the even length strings which do not have 'b' at any of the even positions.

Comment: And its regular expression is: `((a + b)a)*`

Answer (score 1):

You are right. The FA defines a language containing all strings with a succession of `aa` and `ba` . The strings do not start with ab and never contain a bb. A more concise regex is `(aa|ba)*`

Answer (score 0):

Any count of ("aa" or "ba") is possible (0 times too).
As regexp `([ab]a)*`
In other words: Even count of characters, each odd position is a or b, and the rest only a.
Your definition is lacking the "even count" part, to start with.